# A script to render rigged human 3D model in certain pose described by few variables

Tags: 3d, render, fbx, skeletal-animation

I have a rigged human 3D model in .fbx or .zbrush format. I want to write a program that reads the model and displays it (writes to image file) in a certain pose.

I want to define pose by specifying few variables (not more than several hundreds), for example, angles between bones. So, a program gets a model and a list of variables describing pose and returns image.

What tools (languages and libraries) exist to do this?

I know that Unity can load .fbx but I wonder if it is the instrument of choice for my problem. I don't need to animate model dynamicaly: just one call to program - one pose. All I need is high quality of image, I mean high resolution and natural limbs bending, and simplicity of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with Unity 3D:**

**Rotating a bone via scripts**

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/327196/rotating-a-bone-via-scripts.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/985631/how-can-i-rotate-a-bone-from-script.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/126368/how-to-rotate-a-bone-during-an-animation.html

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rotating-a-bone-with-script.312464/

**Capture Screenshot**

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html

https://ralphbarbagallo.com/2012/04/09/3-ways-to-capture-a-screenshot-in-unity3d/

*It would be easier for you to do the rotation manually in any 3D modeling program.*